# Adjust Textview according to variable in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i am building an app in Android Studio using kotlin,

the app is a quiz app with a text in the end depending on the result.

I want to know, what is the smoothest way to move a value(i am guessing intent) from the first activity to the last, adjusting it on the way. And how do i use this value to adjust the string showed on the result activity?

I was thinking of creating strings for all results and name them result100, result200, result300 etc. then have a variable that changes according to the answers such as:

```
buttonParty.setOnClickListener{    
            desNumber = 100
            val intent = Intent(this, ResultPageActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("EXTRA_DES", desNumber)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

retreive it with:

```
val desNumber = intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_DES", 100)
```

than on the last activity:

```
resultText.setText = findViewById(R.string.result$desNumber)
```

But this doesnt seem to work unfortunately.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I suggest you conform to a "Single Activity" architecture and that way you can keep any global variables in a ViewModel scoped to your Activity and read them in your respective fragments by doing `val activityModel by activityViewModels()` in your respective `Fragment`s. Please refer to this video by Android team https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k8x8V77CrU and look up "MVVM" and "Jetpack Navigation". Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with something called [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

So you would do something like this:

-On your parent activity (the first), create your ViewModel that will hold your data, and the functions that will alter (or retrieve) that data:

```
class GameActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
 class GameData: ViewModel(){
        //Creates the variables that hold the data, with a type that allows them to change over time,
        //and to be "observed", but not be useful to this specific example, but this is what I usually use
        private val _Result1 : MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
            MutableLiveData<String>().apply { value = "You got a Low Score" }
        }
        private val _Result2 : MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
            MutableLiveData<String>().apply { value = "You got a High Score" }
        }

        //Publishes the values of the strings without letting them being altered directly
        val Result1 : LiveData<String>
            get() = _Result1
        val Result2 : LiveData<String>
            get() = _Result2
    }
}
```

-On the activity that you want to retrieve the data, do this:

```
    //Declare the variable that will give access to the variables
    private val dataModel : GameActivity.GameData by activityViewModels()

    //Acess the variables
    if(dataModel.Result1.value === "...")
```

While this answer shows how you can create a model to hold your data in one activity, and access in others, I think the way you are doing it (saving different messages to show) might be done better in a different way. Shouldn't you just save the "points" value in the data model, and use conditions to show the different messages?
You can save the points in this data model the same way it's done with the strings above, but with "Int" instead of "String" in the data types.